# TypeError python: unsupported operand

Tags: python

```
from sklearn import cross_validation as cv
train_data, test_data = cv.train_test_split(df, test_size=0.25)

#Create two user-item matrices, one for training and another for testing
train_data_matrix = np.zeros((n_users, n_items))
for line in train_data:
                train_data_matrix[line[0]-1, line[1]-1] = line[2]
```

I am getting the error:

```
File ".....", line 26, in <module>
    train_data_matrix[line[0]-1, line[1]-1] = line[2]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Has anyone any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure but try transforming line[0] and line[1] to int like: train_data_matrix[int(line[0])-1, int(line[1])-1] = line[2]

Comment: If you read the error, it says you're subtracting an `int` from `str`.

Comment: `line[0]` or\and `line[1]` are strings. You cannot subtract `1` from a string.

Comment: @Roomm, I also tried **train_data_matrix[int(line[0])-1, int(line[1])-1] = line[2]** but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

This because your `train_data`, which is a subset of your `df` has character columns in it. You cant subtract a number from a character. You probably wanted to use `train_data_matrix` instead in the loop. In the for loop you are using `train_data` instead of `train_data_matrix`.

Comment: Ok, but now I get this: **ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required**